# how to receive NSWorkspace and accessibility notifications on another thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa

I am trying to do window management, but I need the code running on a separate thread.

The first thing I need to do is subscribe to app notifications like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
NSString *not = NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification;
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(appLaunched:) name:not object:nil];
```

But if I simply call `addObserver` on another thread, will the notifications be delivered there instead?

Apple has this reference, but it seems overcomplicated:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html

If the answer to the first question is no, then why couldn't I just forward the message like this?

```
NSThread *other;

- (void)appLaunched:(NSNotification*)not {
    if([NSThread currentThread] != otherThread)
        [self performSelector:@selector(appLaunched:) onThread:other withObject:not waitUntilDone:NO];
    else
        // do respond to notification
}
```

The second thing I need to do is add an AXObserver to a runloop on the other thread.

If I call `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` from another thread, will a run loop automatically be created like calling `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` or do a I have to create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observers which are registered using `-addObserver:selector:name:object:` receive the notification on the thread where it's **posted**, not where they registered. There's also `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`, which causes the notification to be received on the specified queue, but that doesn't let you make it arrive on a specified background thread. (Only the main queue is tied to a thread.)

You can shunt a notification to another thread in the manner you suggest. However, the original receiving thread has to be idling to receive the notification in the first place. Or, rather, it has to be idling in order to allow `NSWorkspace` to detect the condition which causes it to post the notification.

All threads create a runloop for themselves as soon as it's requested. It's basically impossible to observe a thread not having a runloop, so you might as well just act as though the runloop is created when the thread is created.

All of that said, your original goal – "I am trying to do window management, but I need the code running on a separate thread" – is problematic. Many GUI manipulations are not legal from background threads. Also, why do you "need" to do it from a background thread? And if your main thread is not free, you're not going to receive the workspace notifications in the first place.

Comment: I meant window management of the entire workspace/desktop. My UI has animated buttons, etc, so it has to run smoothly. but if I call AXElement* functions from the main thread, and the target application/window is unresponsive, the calls can block for a long time. In some cases, they fail with kAXErrorCannotComplete because the target app is unresponsive or in an incorrect state, at which point I'm forced to retry until it works, which is a lot easier on a separate thread. Once the observer thread has updated it's state successfully, it will send an update notification back to the main thread.

Comment: additional information here:  http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/218818-how-to-set-up-thread-listening-to-performselector-messages.html